# How to improve a regex expression in order to match "special" letters?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex, ruby-on-rails-3

I am using Ruby on Rails 3.0.9 and I am using the following regex in order to validate a string containing letters, blank spaces and numbers (if I am right, it should match those mentioned characters):

```
/^[\w\s-]*$/u
```

I would like to improve that regex also to match a string that can contain "special" characters\letters as, for example, `'`, `"`, `%`, `&`, `*`, `@`, `!`, `?`, `(`, `)`, `[` and `]`. **How can I change the above regex in order to match those?**

---

**UPDATE**

I forgot that in the above expression I would like to match\validate also *accented* letters as like `à`, `è`, `é`, `ì`, `ò` and `ù`.

Comment: maybe it would be better to make regexp that excludes some set of chars?

Comment: Language note: "Literal" is not a fancy word for "letter" (or even "character"). It means a constant whose value is given directly in the source code. In many languages, `'&'` is a character literal, but `&` itself is just a character.

Comment: @Henning Makholm Thanks very much for the tip.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add the extra characters to your character class while escaping any that have a special meaning inside a regular expression character class (just `[` and `]` in your case):

```
/^[\w\s'"%&*@!?()\[\]-]*$/u
```

Also make sure you put the `-` at the end of the character class or escape it (`\-`) so that the regex parser won't think it is indicating a range.

If you also want to throw in Unicode "word" characters, then replace the `\w` with `\p{Word}`:

```
/^[\p{Word}\s'"%&*@!?()\[\]-]*$/
```

Assuming you're using 1.9 of course. And if you're not using 1.9 then you should upgrade to get better Unicode support.

The `\p{}` syntax for Oniguruma (the 1.9 regex engine for Ruby) is for a named property and it sounds like you're looking for the "word" property so `\p{Word}` is your replacement for `\w`. You might want to replace `\s` with `\p{Space}` while you're at it:

```
/^[\p{Word}\p{Space}'"%&*@!?()\[\]-]*$/
```

Further details on the Oniguruma syntax are available here:

> http://www.geocities.jp/kosako3/oniguruma/doc/RE.txt

Comment: Using your second regex `/^[\p{Word}\s'"-_%&*@!?()\[\]-]*$/` (note: I just added `-_` to it) on validating an expression like `abcd ç #` (in this case validation should fail since in the string there are `ç` and `#` letters) I get the following error: `Encoding::CompatibilityError (incompatible encoding regexp match (ASCII-8BIT regexp with UTF-8 string))`. I am using Ruby 1.9.2.

Comment: @Backo: (1) `"-_` is probably not what you want, that's a range from `"` to `_`. (2) Do you have `# coding: utf-8` in your script to indicate that it is UTF-8 encoded? Works fine for me in `irb`.

Comment: (1) So, I think I should use `/^[\p{Word}\p{Space}\-_'"%&*@!?()\[\]-]*$/` (note use of `\-` as you said in your answer - if I understood that). (2) How can I check if I have `#` `coding: utf-8` in my script to indicate that it is UTF-8 encoded??

Comment: @Backo: I think you want `/^[\p{Word}\p{Space}'"%&*@!?()\[\]_-]*$/u`, no need to mention `-` twice and the `u` modifier should take care of the encoding issue (but I don't know how to reproduce your exception so I'm guessing).

Answer (score 0):

You can escape special characters. This regular expression: `\[\]` will match the string `"[]"`.

Take a look at this useful website: http://www.rubular.com/

You can build up your regex and test it against strings.

**Edit** Just start appending these escaped special characters to your regex, like so: `/^[\'\"\[\]\w\s-]*$/u` There I've appended it such that it can now also look for any occurance of a single quota ('), double quote ("), and square brackets ([]). Just keep adding more if you need it.

Comment: And how I should "code" that that I would like to match? That is, how should look the new regex?